# Excel fill down column with multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel spread sheet in which values in a column are as under:

```
Unit
Type
Sex
```

I want this value to be filled down in column as:

```
Unit
Type
Sex
Unit
Type
Sex
Unit
Type
Sex
```

Would be grateful for any help by the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type in once, select all three values and drag down the auto-filler (small rectangle in right bottom corner of selection).

If you want to fill up a column up to the same number of rows that is present in a neighboring column, then double-click on the auto-filler.

Comment: Tried so many things besides this little one...!
Its working great.. 
But I have large volume data of around 20000 rows.
Is there any way or formula to fill down values in one click

Comment: That depends on the actual table. If there is a neighboring column with 20000 values then double-clicking on the auto-filler will fill your column to the point where the data in the neighboring column ends.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is the following: if your data is in `A1:A3` then just type

```
=A1
```

Into cell `A4` and drag down/fill down